# How to apply UIScrollView's transform to UIView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-graphics, drawrect

In my app I have a scrollview with an added subview called allView.
In the scrollview delegate methods I am applying value of the current transformation of the scrollview's subview to another view called paint view

```
paintView.transform = allView.transform
```

and save it to the disk.

The image that is created in result of that process looks different than the one on the screen. Why? How can I fix it?

**View Controller**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;                                               {
    self.paintView.transform =self.allView.transform;
    [self.paintView setNeedsDisplay];   
}
  - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
         self.backgroundView.transform = self.allView.transform;
        [self.paintView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

**Paint View**

Inside the PaintView's draw rect I am trying to apply transformation from the scroll view and

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

// Drawing code
 // Draw on the screen
    CGContextRef ctx1 =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx1, self.transform);

    CGColorRef wh = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx1, wh);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx1, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx1, 200, 200);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx1);

   // Apply scroll view's transformation
    CGRect  r = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect,self.transform );

    //that gives a resized image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, self.transform);
    // stroke and so on          
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, wh);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 200, 200);
     CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    Getting image with entire content.
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //Clipping the image
    CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
    NSData * d = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.8);
    //saving the image (for debugging)
    [self save:d];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
```

iOS Simulator
[image: Desired Effect]

Image saved to the disk
[image: Result]

Comment: Does this happen only on retina screens, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little bit hard to diagnose the problem here without being able to have running code. However, I think the problem may be on these lines where you are clipping the image:

```
// Clipping the image
CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
```

I think you actually just want to get the scroll view's visible rect, which would be `scrollView.frame` rather than the subview that fills the scroll view's entire `contentSize`. So, using some way (such as a property on `paintView` such as a `visibleFrame`), I would revise the lines to be something like this:

```
// Clipping the image
CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, self.visibleFrame);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
```

Hope this helps you get passed this issue!